# Extracting entitlements from Xcode capabilities

Tags: xcode, xcode5, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I need to obtain an entitlement file generated by Xcode automatically when you're building a project.

Normally (even when you don't have any explicit capabilities selected), you can find one at `$DERIVED_FILES_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.xcent`, it contains generic information about your team and keychain access.

Does anyone know a way to generate it bypassing the build phase.
I want to figure out a flow that is unrelated to the fact whether explicit entitlement file was specified or when Capabilities pane was used to specify them.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a way (thanks to Apple's engineers):

`$ codesign -d --entitlements - /path/to/app/bundle.app`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

hope it helps you, too!